# Can't figure out crash

Tags: c++

Let me start by saying this is a school exercise. I am trying to learn not just copy / paste an answer. Hints in the right direction would be great. I'm sorry if this question doesn't adhere to any rules on this site.

So my problem is I create a set of cards and it lists each card(an int) in an array. The first works fine, but on the 2nd cardset my program crashes.

I left some code out. I'm not worried about all the functions. My program crashes in the constructor area. It compiles fine but crashes in execution. Theres gotta be a really simple error there. Thanks!

CardSet.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CardSet.h"
using namespace std;

CardSet::CardSet()
{
    nCards = 0;
}

CardSet::CardSet(int Input_Card_Amount)
{
    nCards = Input_Card_Amount;
    int quot = (int)nCards / 52;
    int rem = nCards % 52;
    int Sets_Of_Cards = 0;
    int Card_Index = 0;
    while(Sets_Of_Cards != quot)
    {
        for(int Card_Counter = 0; Card_Counter < 52; Card_Counter++)
        {
            Card[Card_Index] = Card_Counter;
            Card_Index++;
        }
        Sets_Of_Cards++;
    }
    for(int Card_Counter = 0; Card_Counter < rem; Card_Counter++)
    {
        Card[Card_Index] = Card_Counter;
        Card_Index++;
    }
}

CardSet::~CardSet()
{
    delete[] Card;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    CardSet CardSet1(12), CardSet2(12), CardSet3, CardSet4, CardSet5, CardSet6;

    cout << "BEGINNING OF CARDSET TESTS . . .  "<< endl << endl;

    cout << "Test 1: Constructors:" << endl;
    cout << "CardSet1 Size: " << CardSet1.Size() << endl;
    cout << "CardSet3 Size: " << CardSet3.Size() << endl;
    cout << "Printout of CardSet1:" << endl;
    CardSet1.Print();
    cout << "Printout of CardSet2:" << endl;
    CardSet2.Print();
    cout << endl;
    enter code here
    cout << ". . . END OF TESTS"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CardSet.h

```
#ifndef CARDSET_H
#define CARDSET_H

class CardSet
{
    public:
        CardSet();
        CardSet(int);
        ~CardSet();
        int Size() const;
        bool IsEmpty() const;
        void Shuffle();
        int Deal();
        void Deal(int,CardSet&,CardSet&);
        void Deal(int,CardSet&,CardSet&,CardSet&,CardSet&);
        void AddCard(int);
        void MergeShuffle(CardSet&);
        void Print() const;
    private:
        int* Card;
        int nCards;
        void PrintCard(int c) const;
};

#endif
```

Comment: where do you allocate memory for `int* Card;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate cards. Sorry I'm answering from my phone so a little tricky but basically you need to go

```
Card = new int[52]
```

Before attempting to access the card array. Ie, before your while loop.

Hope that helps

Comment: Didn't understand what you meant at first. I do now. Thanks!